# Highcharts: Remove extra margin y-axis when plotting multiple series

Tags: jquery, highcharts, padding, linechart

I have a chart with two different datetime series, first series is linear and holds monthly values while the second series is a column series and holds only  one value per year.

When I display both series in one chart (one `x-axis` [datetime], two `y-axes`) the first plot is not drawn on the left side but with a padding to the y-axis ([see example here](http://jsfiddle.net/kaiw/zmf6ubqg/)).

```
series: [{
        name: 'Monthly',
        type: 'line',
        yAxis: 0,
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2012, 0, 31), 11],
            [Date.UTC(2012, 1, 28), 12],
            [Date.UTC(2012, 2, 31), 13],
            (...etc...)
            [Date.UTC(2014, 9, 31), 22],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 30), 21],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 11, 31), 20]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Yearly',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2012, 5, 30), 16],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 30), 17],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 30), 18]
        ]
    }]
```

If I put only the linear series in the chart ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/kaiw/zmf6ubqg/3/)), the plots are being nicely put to the left and right extremes of the chart. This is what I want to achieve for the linear/column combination as well.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs because your second series `'Yearly'`, has data point in the *middle* of the year. What Highcharts always does is first calculate the intervals of the different series. In your case, it therefore scales the x-axis according to the interval of the second series, which is in years:

```
        [Date.UTC(2012, 5, 30), 16],   
        [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 30), 17],   // year after last datapoint
        [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 30), 18]    // year after last datapoint
```

Then, it will try to put the x-axis starting point at such a datapoint: `Date.UTC(2012, 5, 30)` (the first one preferably). Only problem: your *first* series starts *before* this datapoint and has a *smaller* interval between its datapoints. What highcharts does then is choose the *largest* interval (years in your case) and then try to find the interval below the lowest datapoint.

For your case this is therefore:

```
Date.UTC(2012, 0, 31) - a year
(lowest datapoint)     (largest interval)
```

Same holds for the upper limit of the x-axis.

I have a found a way to calculate this difference and compensate for it:

```
var begin        = Date.UTC(2012, 0, 31);     // the earliest/first time of both series
var end          = Date.UTC(2014, 11, 31);    // the latest/last time of both series
var beginLargest = Date.UTC(2012, 5, 30);     // the first time of the series with the
                                              // .. largest interval between datapoints
var endLargest   = Date.UTC(2014, 5, 30);     // the last time of the series with the
                                              // .. largest interval between datapoints

var yearRange    = (end - begin)/(365*60*60*24*1000);
var yearBegExtra = (beginLargest - begin)/(365*60*60*24*1000);
var yearEndExtra = (endLargest - end)/(365*60*60*24*1000); 
var marginBegin  = yearBegExtra / yearRange;
var marginEnd    = yearEndExtra / yearRange;
```

Now we can compensate for this extra margin as follows:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    minPadding: -marginBegin + 0.005,    // +0.005 to give a little extra padding
    maxPadding: marginEnd    + 0.005    // .. which allows to see the ticks 2012 & 2015
}, ..
```

This gives the chart as expected.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jzgbg0hg/)

[image]